# Application defined or object defined error occur when I run a macro to merge cells in a protected sheet & press cancel in message box

Tags: vba, excel, merge, protected

**Application defined or object defined error** occur when I press **cancel** appear in the [Message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqNlD.png) after running the following macro:

```
Sub MergeCells()
'
' MergeCells Macro
' merge selected cells but preserve formatting ability for unlocked cells
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
'
Const myPassword = "ldc"

ActiveSheet.Unprotect myPassword
Selection.Cells.Merge
ActiveSheet.Protect myPassword, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=False, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True


End Sub
```

The function of macro is to merge cells in a protected sheet.

Comment: have you stepped through the code to see if your password is working?

Comment: yes i have stepped through the code, It works fine when OK is pressed but giveS error if cancel is pressed

Comment: Do you want to give the user the option to Cancel?  If not then you can add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the call to `Merge`

Comment: @werdakloi Tim is correct, if you don't want them to be able to cancel, then application.displayalerts = false before the call, otherwise, throw a messagebox with an if/then statement on the reply with an "exit sub" to the cancel and you should be fine

Comment: @RichardU-would this solve the "Application defined or object defined error "?